# What is the force that generated by a moving car on the road?

Tags: thermodynamics, forces

Foce or vibration on road surface are usually depending on the speed and the wight of the car.

Comment: Please consider adding something to your question that makes it clearly understandable

Comment: so  what exactly are you asking about ?

Answer (score 1):

> **What is the force that generated by a moving car on the road?**

It is the force from the engine, transmitted through the driven tyres. This force opposes frictional forces including wind-resistance.

There are also forces on the road that are generated during accelleration (by the engine) and decelleration (by the brakes)

These forces are principally horizontal, along the surface of the road

There is also, of course a vertical force due to gravity but that is not related to movement.

Since roads are not perfectly smooth and wheels are not perfectly balanced, there are also forces due to the oscillation of various parts of the vehicle as it rises and falls in response to the uneven surface and to other induced movements.